# Full width div for all screen resolution

Tags: css, html

I've been working with a html page that has a form in the bottom of the page. That form is inside a table and table is inside a div. Fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/2ZTvQ/

Problem is on smaller screen the div is taking 100% width(full width of the screen) but not width of the whole table containing the form. I'm not an expert with html/css so I'm not even sure if it can be done this way.

Sample HTML:

```
<div class='wide'>
    <table width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td>
                looooooooooooooo ooooooooooo00000  ooooooong text goes here
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wide {
    text-align:center;
    background:#e7e7e4;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top:20px;
}
```

Comment: For one thing, avoid using tables.

Comment: Its either tables or divs. Never use them together. I think you can code without table substituting it with div

Comment: @TejasPatel Unless you're writing an *actual* table :P

Comment: @TejasPatel: I've tried using table only. Same result

Comment: @Fallen I never ever use table now. First I used to when I didn't understand div better. But than I studied many sites like google, facebook all of them use div. So try using only divs

Comment: I find the question ambigious. How can div take up whole screen width but not the table contained inside it. Is there scroll bar in table

Comment: @TejasPatel: There are other tables on this page with fixed width. I'm just adding this form. Other part was done by someone else

Answer (score 0):

Remove `text-align:center;` or create a new aligning style for the table.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you will have to do is add a min-width to .wide of however small the table will get after manually trying to reduce it's width. So once it is as small as you can get it (use media queries to change classes under a certain window width) set

```
.wide { min-width: thatSize; }
```

What will happen now is instead of the content disappearing or running out of the div, you will now just have to scroll horizontally to see it all.

Or what you can do is add

```
.wide { overflow: scroll; }
```

What that will do is keep the viewport the same size, but make the content inside .wide scrollable like an iframe. Probably better looking than the first solution. Whatever you decide is a design choice on your part. But most important thing would be using media queries and trying to get the form as thin as possible. Display block and percentage widths are your friends there.